# Default control of user profile

Tags: user-profile, user, user-controls

I want to use user link in my aspx page. How to reproduce default sharepoint profile/user link?

Link control examples on pictures:

[image: default user control]

on hovering

[image: pic 2]

Comment: You need to add more details. What are you trying to accomplish and in what language?

Comment: I want to reproduce this control in code behind, on my aspx page.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ekraus/2008/02/06/use-peopleeditor-people-picker-in-sharepoint-custom-app-dev/

Comment: thx, but this control is not what I'm looking for. I need to see this picture 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing this in SharePoint or outside? The Profile Card is built from JavaScript hosted in SharePoint. You can pass parameters to the getUserPersona function, but recreating the card outside of SharePoint would be easier if you roll your own function after calling the getter for the User Profile Service (or the Search API) and pass the user account or sip address that you are trying to display.

I walk through the different options here: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/add-presence-to-sharepoint-search-results/